# Identity Custom Attribute not populating (Saving to Database Works)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, properties, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to extend the identity model with a custom field that is called RefModels.
The problem is that when I fetch the user through the user manager, the users `RefModel` propertie is empty (null).even when it is filled out in the database.

Reference Model:

```
 public class Refmodel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Ref { get; set; }
}
```

Identity Extending:

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
 
    public List<Refmodel> RefModel { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: it's hard to say what's the issue without a minimal reproducible code sample. I suspect this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `ApplicationUser` and `UserId` field to RefModel class to define navigation property

```cs
 public class Refmodel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```